# HTML Validation

Tags: html, validation

**1. there is no attribute X**

You have used the attribute named above in your document, but the document type you are using does not support that attribute for this element. This error is often caused by incorrect use of the "Strict" document type with a document that uses frames (e.g. you must use the "Transitional" document type to get the "target" attribute), or by using vendor proprietary extensions such as "marginheight" (this is usually fixed by using CSS to achieve the desired effect instead).

This error may also result if the element itself is not supported in the document type you are using, as an undefined element will have no supported attributes; in this case, see the element-undefined error message for further information.

How to fix: check the spelling and case of the element and attribute, (Remember XHTML is all lower-case) and/or check that they are both allowed in the chosen document type, and/or use CSS instead of this attribute. If you received this error when using the  element to incorporate flash media in a Web page, see the FAQ item on valid flash.

```
Line 335, column 52: there is no attribute "key"

…t type="text" value="Full Name:"  key="Full Name:" name="txtFullName" id="txtF…

Line 341, column 78: there is no attribute "value"

…"txtMessage" cols="22" rows="3" value="Project" style="color:#707070;" class="…
```

I have checked my HTML but unable to find solution. Can any one guide me what should be the possible solution of this problem. Can some one explain?

Comment: What is the `key` attribute for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you use attribute "key" (key="Full Name:") that is not in HTML specifications. Remove it and it will be ok.

Comment: So you need to modify you javascript to make your html valid or just don't worry about html validity, because all modern browsers will process your page correctly in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your Doctype. If you assign the correct Doctype then you will solve your problem. Unfortunately I can't help you further because I don't know what is your current Doctype and what elements you are using. Give me the web page to pass the validation and I will give you a solution.

Comment: Line 31 : Change all & instances with &amp;
Line 335 : Remove key property. Input elements cannot have key property.
Line 341 : Remove value property. Textarea cannot have value property.
Add a </div> before </body>

Comment: The above should make your document valid for XHTML 1.0 Transitional

Comment: Rate me up please if my answer was corect ! :) Thanks :D

Comment: Yes your </div> idea helped me remove one error..although i do not understand its logic as i have checked my HTML multiple time to find out which div is not closed but i were unable to find it. Thanks any way

Comment: Ok. Do a search into your HTML code. In any place you find a & symbol just convert it to &amp; and from fields <input type="text" remove the attribute key="....". Another think you have to do is to remove the attribute value="" from <textarea ....>...</textarea> elements. That changes will remove all your errors !

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the output from the validator, it appears that you have a `key` attribute on what looks likely to be an `input` element. That's invalid, because there is no such thing as a `key` attribute.

From the [HTML 4.01 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4), valid attributes on `input` elements are (`key` is not on the list):

```
<!ATTLIST INPUT
  %attrs;                              -- %coreattrs, %i18n, %events --
  type        %InputType;    TEXT      -- what kind of widget is needed --
  name        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- submit as part of form --
  value       CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- Specify for radio buttons and checkboxes --
  checked     (checked)      #IMPLIED  -- for radio buttons and check boxes --
  disabled    (disabled)     #IMPLIED  -- unavailable in this context --
  readonly    (readonly)     #IMPLIED  -- for text and passwd --
  size        CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- specific to each type of field --
  maxlength   NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- max chars for text fields --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- for fields with images --
  alt         CDATA          #IMPLIED  -- short description --
  usemap      %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- use client-side image map --
  ismap       (ismap)        #IMPLIED  -- use server-side image map --
  tabindex    NUMBER         #IMPLIED  -- position in tabbing order --
  accesskey   %Character;    #IMPLIED  -- accessibility key character --
  onfocus     %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element got the focus --
  onblur      %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element lost the focus --
  onselect    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- some text was selected --
  onchange    %Script;       #IMPLIED  -- the element value was changed --
  accept      %ContentTypes; #IMPLIED  -- list of MIME types for file upload --
  >
```

Nor is `key` a valid attribute according to the current version of the [HTML living standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-input-element.html).

If you are using that attribute to store arbitrary data (for use in JavaScript for example), I would recommend using the `data-*` attributes instead:

`<input type="text" data-key="Whatever you like">`

Comment: I have tried it, it does not effect functionality but it does not recognize "data" or "data-key" as a valid attribute

Comment: You will have to use `<!DOCTYPE html>` as your `DOCTYPE` for it to validate `data-*` attributes. They are new as part of the latest HTML in-progress standard.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have attributes that are not in the spec as metioned here, but if you use the HTML5 doctype, you can have any attributes with a `data-` prefix. You could rename the attribute to `data-key`. This would be accessible via Javascript.

If you cannot use the HTML5 doctype, then you could use a hidden field with a similar name as the textbox, such as `txtFullNameHidden' to store the key.